# What is proper term for a flow chart for mobile app?

Tags: information-architecture, wireframe, workflow, mobile-application, sitemap

I am creating a *user flow* aka *flow chart* aka *information flow chart* using Balsamiq, not using Omnigraffle or other tools, for a mobile app.  What is the proper term for this diagram?

See [Gustav Shiring's Moodswings wireframes](http://www.klotjohan.se) for reference.

[Related UXSE question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7049/how-do-you-map-the-flow-of-a-mobile-application-can-you-provide-examples)

Comment: I think it can be termed as interaction model

Comment: An interaction model is certainly different from a flowchart. Not a definitive source, but some deeper reading into a proper interaction model can be found here: http://uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2012/01/defining-an-interaction-model-the-cornerstone-of-application-design.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I finally found the exact diagram and answers I was looking for. They're called **mobile app visual flow charts**.

Slight variation from flowcharts in @BennySkoberg answer.

> **Merging of wireframes with flows.** As the above artifact mixes readable screens with flows or user actions, the element of time and
> narrative begins to emerge. Since the flow diagram is inseparable from
> the wireframe, it also saves the designer from the extra effort of
> synchronizing multiple documents.
>
> **Transition references**. Although not
> visible in the sample, the blue circles are actual links to .mov files
> that show short video demos of the transitions. Wires plus video feels
> fresh!
>
> **Screen references**. All of the screens have an ID tag, and
> occasionally actions lead to screen references instead of full screens
> – a way of reusing and again minimizing duplication efforts. Also each
> screen links to a folder with source PNG layout files.
>
> **Action references**. Most user actions here also have an ID with a distinct
> style and can therefore also be referred to.
>
> **Starting Point**. Since the
> canvas is quite large it has a clear starting point to guide the
> viewer.
>
> **Layout structure**. In the top right of the canvas, the core
> structure of the layout along with some popular components are
> explained.
>
> **Toggle-able layers.** Various information is kept separate on
> distinct layers and so that it’s possible to toggle it on and off for
> various audiences.

- http://wireframes.linowski.ca/tag/user-flow/
- https://creativemarket.com/ericmillerdesign/17032-Mobile-App-Visual-Flowchart-AI
- http://uxkits.com/products/mobile-app-visual-flowchart-illustrator-template

[image]

Screenshot taken from [Anton Volkov](http://dribbble.com/fireupman)'s user flow chart on [Wireframes Magazine](http://wireframes.linowski.ca/2012/09/large-canvas-flows-with-references/).

Answer (score 4):

A flowchart is a [flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) regardless of which device it is viewed on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a more specific term for mobile flowcharts with touch gestures incorporated e.g. tap and drag to show navigation drawer?

Comment: @Danger14 I'll see and get back to you!

Comment: True @BennySkogberg, however the question isn't asking about flow charts viewed on mobile devices, he's asking about charts depicting the flow of a user through a mobile application (possibly as viewed on a mobile devices, but also possibly as viewed on a papyrus scroll or carved into a tree).

Comment: @Erics I must have misinterpreted "in Balsamiq for a mobile app" then,